# Reiniciar Mysql antes de que llegue el maximo de conexiones

Tags: mysql, bash, shell

Tengo una BBDD MySql corriendo en una maquina Debian en GCP, que en ocasiones llega al limite de conexiones, con lo cual deja la aplicación  parada hasta que se reinicia y entonces la aplicación ya puede volver a conectarse.

Actualmente tiene como numero máximo de conexiones tiene 1000, mi idea era crear un script que mirara la BBDD sacara el numero de conexiones y si superaba los 950 reiniciara la BBDD. la idea es meterlo en un Crontab que se ejecute cada 5 minutos.

De momento lo que llevo es hasta aquí y no he conseguido hacerlo funcionar mas (soy un manta :)   )  La dos datos de las conexiones son de pruebas, reinicia cuando hay mas de tres conexiones.

```
sudo mysql < in.txt > out.txt;

sudo grep -o '[0-9]' <out.txt >connections.txt
#maxconnections=$(cat connections.txt)
maxconnections=$(awk '{ print $1 }' connections.txt)
echo  $maxconnections
sleep 4
if [[$maxconnections -ge "3"]]; then  service mysql restart
else
    echo "por debajo de las conexiones maximas"
    sleep 3
fi ;
```

El fichero in.txt tiene el siguiente comando:

```
show status where `variable_name` = 'Threads_connected';
```

El fichero out tiene el resultado de ejecutar el comando del fichero in.txt:

```
Variable_name   Value
Threads_connected       2
```

El fichero connections solo contiene el numero de conexiones, en contrato: 2

Al ejecutar el script me da el siguiente error:

```
root@test-mysql:/home/aminiasin/temp# ./script.sh 
2
./script.sh: line 11: [[2: command not found
```

una o menos

```
root@test-mysql:/home/aminiasin/temp#
```

Alguna pista de porque puede estar fallando?

Comment: no es mas facil aumentar el limite de conexiones o colocarlo ilimitado? estas tomando en cuenta el riesgo que es bajar la base de datos y que no levante

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverFlow, te invito a hacer el [tour] asi ganaras unas medallas y sabras como funcionamos

Comment: Vas a bajar una base productiva porque llego al limite de conexiones, mientras los usuarios la estan usando? creo que deberias revisar tu arquitectura, algo no esta bien si queres hacer eso...

Comment: Si, estamos trabajando en solucionar el problema...normalmente en uso normal no tiene mas de 300/325 conexiones concurrentes maximas.  Esto es un "apaño" temporal.

Comment: humm si estan en fase de debug, tal vez te convenga instalar monit https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-install-and-configure-monit-on-debian-9/ te permite definir un script que monitorea envia alertas y reinicia servicios con ciertos límites. onda email alert al 75% restart al 90% asi tenes un margen de entrar y monitorear que es lo que provoca el spike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
./script.sh: line 11: [[2: command not found
```

Ese error radica principalmente en tu sentencia `if`

```
if [[$maxconnections -ge "3"]]; then  service mysql restart
```

Este `[[$maxconnections` no tiene sentido para bash. Ya que, al parecer, cuando la variable $maxconnections se expande como "2", entonces tienes el token `[[2` en tu script corriendo. Pero ese token no tiene significado alguno. Lo que tiene significado sería algo como

```
[[ $maxconnections -ge "3" ]]
# |_______________________|______ Nota estos espacios.
```

Entonces, si volviera a sustituirse el número 2 en `$maxconnections`, la sentencia quedaría de la forma `if [[ 2 -ge "3" ]]` y eso ya cobra sentido puesto que `if` ejecuta comandos basado en una condicional y esa condicional se da al evaluarse con el *built-in* `[[` que es un token que utiliza bash para evaluar. Como todo token, necesita de un separador que lo identifique, en este caso es un espacio antes y después `if [[ condicion ]]`

Tu script debería quedar algo de este estilo.

```
sudo mysql < in.txt > out.txt;

sudo grep -o '[0-9]' <out.txt >connections.txt
maxconnections=$(awk '{ print $1 }' connections.txt)
echo  $maxconnections
if [[ $maxconnections -ge "3" ]]
then
    service mysql restart
else
    echo "por debajo de las conexiones maximas"
fi
```

No digo que tu script haga lo correcto, creo que la opción de @Bryro es la indicada. Y referente a tu duda en el script que escribió @Bryro tendrías que poner algo así.

```
if [[ $NUM -ge $MAX ]]
then 
    service mysql restart
fi
```

Pero recuerda no copiar y pegar todo lo que veas inmediatamente, antes revisa la sintaxis, lo que quiso dar a entender el autor del código.

Answer (score 1):

puedes hacerlo asi:

> **nota:** lo coloco solo como material didactico no como una posible solucion a tu problema ya que lo mejor seria aumentar el numero de conexiones de forma temporal:

```
SET GLOBAL max_connections = 3000;
```

> o de forma permanente en `my.ini` y reiniciamos la base de datos:

```
max_user_connections=3000
```

y este el codigo solicitado:

```
#!/bin/bash
MAX=5
NUM=$(cat in.txt  | grep "connected" | awk '{print $2}')
if [[ $NUM -ge $MAX ]]; then
 echo "es mayor de $MAX lo que quieras hacer"
fi
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta.  Creo que casi esta, usando el codigo, ahora no me da error, pero no reinicia la instancia. sudo mysql < in.txt > out.txt;
 
MAX=5
NUM=$(cat out.txt  | grep "connected" | awk '{print $2}')
if [[ $NUM -ge $MAX ]]; then
 echo service mysql restart        Dentro del Cat he cambiado el fichero de out.txt que es el que tiene el numero de conexiones como segundo campo en la linea...no da error pero no reinicia, no se si me falta algunas comillas o alguna otra cosa..

Comment: a que te refieres con material didactico?

Comment: de que no deberia ser usado solo que mire como podria hacer el script!